# H14 code error on Node.js app with Python dependencies on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I've had an an H14 code error while deploying my Node.js application on Heroku. The application calls a Python script, so it has some packages dependencies.

I followed the documentation, in other words my buildpacks are as follows:

1. `heroku/nodejs`
2. `heroku/python`

I have a `requirements.txt` file in root directory, and a `runtime.txt` containing `python-3.6.3`.

The `package.json` is configured as well here's its content:

```
 {
  "name": "spam-community",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This app is a spam and ham detector",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Zadi younes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.17",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "sendmail": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  }
}
```

I tried to set the web demons to one as well with the command `heroku ps:scale web=1` but I get the error

> Couldn't find that process type (web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The order of your buildpacks is important](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#viewing-buildpacks):

> The last buildpack in the list will be used to determine the [process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) for the application. Any process types defined from earlier buildpacks will be ignored.
>
> You can run `heroku help buildpacks` to get a full list of options for the command.

Try moving `heroku/nodejs` after `heroku/python`:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
```

Verify your buildpacks with `heroku:buildpacks`.

This will be especially important if you don't have a `Procfile`. In that case [your `start` script will be run automatically](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type), assuming `heroku/nodejs` is your last buildpack.